# How handle different threads in recursive function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, recursion

I have a recursive function to calculate factorial and i want to make calculation in background thread, how to handle it? 
I'm trying this:

```
func factorial(of number: Double) -> Double {
    var result: Double = 0
    if number > 170 {
        return Double.infinity
    }
    if number != Double(Int(number)) || number < 1 {return 0}
    if number == 1 {
        return 1
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        result = number * factorial(of: number - 1)
    }
    return result 
}
```

I understand that this is wrong, but i don't understand how i have to do.
Thank's for help!

Comment: Write a very standard factorial function, and just call it through dispatch queue.

Comment: Since result at 'n' depends on result at 'n-1', parallel/asynchronous calculation doesn't make much sense.  Put the entire calculation onto one background queue but do its internal calculations in-line.

Comment: If you need to wait for the result, what's the point of doing it in the background?

Comment: And what's the point of using recursion for this? That's a lot of needless overhead for a simple calculation that has no need for recursion at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation would be to split it into synchronous and asynchronous functions:

```
func factorial(of number: Double, completion: @escaping (Double) -> ()) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let result = factorial(of: number)
        DispatchQueue.main.sync { //I don't know what thread you're intending to use, so I picked main :)
            completion(result)
        }
    }
}

func factorial(of number: Double) -> Double {

    var result: Double = 0
    if number > 170 {
        return Double.infinity
    }
    if number != Double(Int(number)) || number < 1 {return 0}
    if number == 1 {
        return 1
    }

    result = number * factorial(of: number - 1)

    return result
}
```

This allows the meet of the work to happen in whichever way you want, without having to worry about potential threading issues.

Comment: It's that i want! Thank's!

Comment: "I don't know what thread you're intending to use" - that's why you shouldn't use main.  ;) Just use global(), and let the caller decide where to handle the completion handler. Otherwise, perfect solution  :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need an async operation here, but you can (or maybe should) refactor the code.

One example might be:

```
func factorial(n: Int) -> Int {
    return (2...n).reduce(1, *)
}
```

However if you *did* want to dispatch some work on a background thread, then likely you would probably be best off dispatching it at the call-site.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print(factorial(n: 12))
}
```

If for some reason your code could not run on the main thread, and you wanted the main thread to wait (which is a bad idea for expensive operations) then you can use `sync` instead of `async`

Comment: Thank's for answer! And nice factorial function, but i can't use it, i need calculations with double